# In Linux terminal, what would "grep -q '/dev/sda1' /proc/mounts || ..." do?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to make a bootable USB device by following this page.
http://planet-lab.org/node/172

It asks me to do these to steps:

```
umount /dev/sda*
grep -q /dev/sda1 /proc/mounts || dd if=PlanetLab-BootCD-3.3.usb of=/dev/sda1
```

But it makes me confused.
Since I think /dev/sda is my HDD, I thought it should be `unmount /dev/sdb*` in order to unmount USB device.

And I really don't understand what `grep -q /dev/sda1 /proc/mounts` is doing.
It seems to check whether "/dev/sda1" is mounted, but I don't exactly know what are the two parameters of grep command is doing. I know `-q` is for quiet.
And I also know `dd` can write an image to a drive.

Comment: [This site](http://explainshell.com/) can be very helpful for things like this or really explaining any shell command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions state

> assuming that the device is detected as /dev/sda

If the assumption is different from the actual mount point, you must modify the commands to match your configuration.

The `grep -q` is used to test for existence without cluttering the screen with the text which is found.  The two parameters are

1. the text sought "/dev/sda1", and
2. the file in which the text is sought "/proc/mounts".

In other scripts, you may see something like

```
grep /dev/sda1 /proc/mounts >/dev/null
```

to achieve the same effect as the `-q` option.